# Angular 4 : Binding dropdown with huge data set(10000+ records)

Tags: angular, performance, autocomplete, dropdownbox

I am trying to bind Angular drop-down (Angular 4+) with 10000+ records, it's  hanging the application, we are unable to perform any other operation post that.

I am just using *ngFor, for the same

```
 <select class="form-control browser-default col-md-12" name="attributeName" [(ngModel)]="attributeName">
      <option *ngFor="let item of typeArray" [ngValue]="item">
                {{item}}
       </option>
  </select>
```

I tried solutions like ng2-auto-complete and ng2-completer  as well but when i start typing the app is hanging because the data is huge.
Any other feasible solution?

Comment: Use a `trackBy` on your `ngFor`, and try have a look at virtual scroll from material. Otherwise fix it on the server side by using an auto complete but use the server to query the data

Comment: @PierreDuc Unfortunately we cant do anything from server side now . I need a mechanism  by which i can imitate infinite scroll from client side only.

Comment: `ng-select` is the best way we load 26000 data in drop down - which takes not even a second check this [https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates

Comment: @RahulSwamynathan i'm trying.. could you tell me how do i bind array of string into the select ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The component that you used were pretty useless. All of them had a change detection set to default and that makes them slow. Using a tip from @RahulSwamynathan I managed to get ng-select, it uses OpPush as a CD mechanism, to work and it is very fast. For testing, I used 26000 UUIDs and the slow down was unnoticeable. But what seems to make it work is the `virtualScroll` option set to true.

```
<ng-select [items]="arrayWithStrings" [virtualScroll]="true" [formControlName]="'name'"></ng-select>
```

If you want to have a styling that comes from the component you have to add `@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css";` in your `style.css` file.

Comment: does it support angular 4 ? When i imported the module, i got this error : SCRIPT5007: Object expected

Comment: what browser did you use? It looks like something that browser would throw.

Comment: IE 11 is the browser . and my array is like : ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a"........];